# What are our options to update this brick facade?

Tags: painting, brick, masonry

I'm interested in updating the look of the brick facade on our house. The first image shows the wall and planter below the window and the two planters by the entry way.

[image]

The previous owner painted the brick red and the mortar white and we want to get back to a more natural, monochromatic, color scheme. Our initial thought was just to repaint the brick but I 'm wondering what other options exist short of replacing the brick?

So, assuming we want to reach a more of a dark gray color, what would you do? What are my options other than painting the brick again?

Thanks!

Comment: That is a very "natural" color scheme for brick... But you could certainly paint over it. Replacing the brick is probably not an option, unless that is brick veneer... and even then sounds like a heck of a lot of work for dubious gain.

Comment: If my picture were better you'd realize there is nothing natural about what's going on there.  It's a very 'hacky' cartoon-ish red and white.

Answer (score 1):

Your cheapest route would be to paint it by far. If you want to change the texture of the wall, have it stuccoed. That can be done in 2 ways, a 3 coat system with a cement based finish or the 3rd coat can be a latex based product that is normally used in EIFS, (exterior insulated finishing system) The color is part of the finish coat with either system.

The top row of brick will need to be removed to tie the stucco in under the siding edge, leaving the brick there will create a water trap and allow water to get behind the brick. This system is around 3/4" to 1" thick. It can be thicker, sometimes thinner, but I would not let anybody try it.

Comment: If we chose to paint it how should we prep the surface before painting?  Pressure wash it?  If we were to go with the stucco can the finished surface be smooth or is it textured?

Comment: Power washing is the accepted norm for prep as long as the surface is clean and free of loose paint. Stucco can be finished in a variety of textures from very rough to a light "sanded" finish. I have not seen stucco in a slick smooth surface, always with at least a slight texture. I guess it could go smooth like plaster.